# Get static instance name in Java via reflection during construction

Tags: java, reflection

I am not sure if this is the right way to reduce number of characters written, but still.

Right now I have the following piece of code that maps to two settings sources: database and .properties file:

```java
import lombok.*;

@Getter
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode
public final class Setting<T> {
    private String id;
    private Class<T> clazz;  

    private Setting(final String id, final Class<T> clazz) {
        this.id = id;
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public static final Setting TOKEN_LENGTH = new Setting("TOKEN_LENGTH", Integer.class);
    // lots of other settings
}
```

The thing is, I want to avoid explicit passing of the first argument to the constructor, e.g. like variable named `TOKEN_LENGTH` has id `TOKEN_LENGTH` passed to it. In other way, when these `static final` variables are instantiated, their first argument is always the name of the said variable.

In this case there are only ~60 instances of this class are created and this happens only at application startup, so any overhead caused by reflection is acceptable.

I wonder if there any way to rewrite the constructor to look something like

```java
    private Setting(final Class<T> clazz) {
        this.id = /* some crazy reflection magic */
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }
```

So, the question is:

➥ By chance, is there any way to get name of static variable for which the object is being instantiated and assigned to?

**UPD:**

There is a solution that first instantiates all variables and then sequentally sets `id` field. I'm still looking for the way to do it "atomically" in constructor.

Comment: So in this case id should equal 'Setting'?

Comment: @MatthewKerian I meant for `public static final Setting SETTING_A` `id` should be `SETTING_A`, and for `public static final Setting ANOTHER_ONE` `id` should be `ANOTHER_ONE`. Sorry if my wording was weird. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's relatively easy to do so, the problem is knowing which field to use. You can mark it with an annotation which would make it easier. Something like

```
public String getFieldName(){
    Field[] fields = getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    for(Field f: fields){
        if(f.isAnnotationPresent(YourAnnotation.class)){
             return f.getName();
        }
    }
    // do whatever if a valid field wasn't found
}
```

If you don't want an annotation then you'll have to find some other way to identify it, such as the only static field. But that's very bad practice and using an annotation is better.

Comment: Thanks, I thought about this too, but wouldn't this lead to an unique annotation for each `public static final` field? I mean, If I have 63 of these different setting variables, shouldn't I create 63 different annotations to differentiate between these variables?

Comment: @Xobotun not if they're all in different classes. You would just run it in the constructor

Comment: Hm-m-m. Right now all these variables are in the same class. Creating 63 different classes just simply won't do. Plus there's already some code that iterates over all static fields in `Setting.java` treating it as enum with generic.

Maybe creating anonymous classes with a sole field in them would do the trick, but how then I am supposed to access that field in _anonymous_ class?.. Now I'm getting more inclined to think it's just impossible in Java. :(

Comment: So you're creating 63 static Settings variables in the same class. The only thing I think would be possible. Don't initialize the ID right away. After all the static fields are initialized, go around and loop through each field, manually set the value of id equal to the name of the field.

Comment: Yes, I think that would be the best. I hope there wouldn't be any concurrent issues. Thanks.